# How to update a label out of gridview by TemplateField checkbox in that gridview without postback

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox, asp.net-ajax

I have a gridview and every row has a checkbox at first column. I bind datagridview to a datasource of bills. I want to display the sum of the bills' that is checked on a label which is out of the gridview. And also i don't want the checkbox do postback. I try to do this with javascript(onclick event of asp:checkbox) but couldn't achieved. I also try AjaxControlToolkit but again unsuccess.

Please help.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%"
                    CssClass="gv">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Seç" HeaderStyle-Width="50px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" Checked="false"/>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceDate" HeaderText="Fatura Tarihi" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Tutar" DataFormatString="{0:N2} TL">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
 </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned, you have also tried JS for your solution. so here i am posting your solution in JS. 
i supposed your **label** id **lbl** (where you want to show the sum of corresponding column name Tutar ).
your label

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

you just need to add a class to your checkbox. i used **mychk**.
so your code for checkbox would be like this

```
Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Seç" HeaderStyle-Width="50px">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" Checked="false" class="mychk" />
          </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

and your jquery would be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var sum = parseInt($('#lbl').html()) || 0;
            $('.mychk input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    sum += parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').html()) || 0;
                } else {
                    sum -= parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').html()) || 0;
                }
                $('#lbl').html(sum);
            });
        }); 
</script>
```

it will show you sum when you `check` or `uncheck` the `checkboxes`